# TerraGo geopdf vs. Esri geopdf

Tags: pdf, geopdf, geospatial-pdf

I am looking for feedback from people who are familiar with both TerraGo and Esri's respective geospatial pdf functions. I understand TerraGo offers a broader spectrum of functionality, but wonder if TerraGo's enhancements have been worth anyone's while.

Answer (score 4):

Coincidentally, about 4 hours before you posted this question, @EsriFederalGovt posted a link to this webcast announcement:

http://content.carahsoft.com/vo/?FileID=a86c5806-f5c1-4fb6-a2c6-0e6118a97aef&m=cb5739226d8ea34d9e5d43301b9c0653&MailID=18712201.

Here are some of the enhancements they list for the latest version of GeoPDF:

> -Produce GeoPDF maps and imagery
>   directly from ArcGIS 10, plus import
>   and view GeoPDF products within ArcGIS
>
> -Extend the access of maps and imagery
>   from ArcGIS to those in the field with
>   GeoPDF products that feature advanced
>   layer control and collaboration
>   capabilities
>
> -Update the GeoPDF product anywhere,
>   whether in a connected or an offline
>   environment, with current,
>   georeferenced markups, notes, audio,
>   video, and more
>
> -Share updated geospatial information
>   within the enterprise between
>   organizations and disparate systems,
>   peer-to-peer, to the field and back

Answer (score 2):

Here is the hyperlink for a fact sheet from TerraGO illustrating the differences between the GeoPDF vs. the one generated by ESRI as default.

http://www.terragotech.com/products/terrago-publisher/geopdf-vs-geospatial-pdf

[image: screen capture]

Great list that really showcases the differences. I will never use the ESRI default Geospatial PDF because it just looks like junk. I spend lots of times cleaning and organizing and grouping all my data in the TOC (table of contents) and none of it is honored or recorded correctly in the ESRI Geospatial PDF.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really like to dis them. But I haven't had much success getting it implemented.
I think if I spent some time with it and had a strong compelling reason for pushing pdf as an editing/markup standard it would be different.
The company has been good to work with and has offered to connect me with help.
I just haven't had the time to devote.

I think the first question you need to answer is. Absolutely you cannot accomplish what you want to accomplish without pdf.

Then it will be an education exercise with you and your users.

You need to make the toolbar easily accessible for install and teach how to useit and for what.

Then I think all the other stuff can be worked out.